# Images in Swing GUI-NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, background, netbeans-6.9

I already designed many JPanel's for my application in **Netbeans** now i want to ..

1. Add background images to all jpanel's in which i had some jcomponents  already.
2. And i want it to do it for jdialog too.
3. I need to design a JMenu with images and menu name.

But already i saw many examples for background images in that they are adding there components through coding im doing it in Netbeans.Is it possible to set it for the main JFrame then i can  leave the jpanel's.

Answer (score 1):

If you use netbeans background image can be added using a simple method. I don't know whether it is a good practice, but it is really easy. See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOLJQ6lsFGE) video.